# Flask import app from parent directory

Tags: python, flask

I have an app structured like so:

```
name
    -app.py
    -__init__.py
    -folder1
            -views.py
            -models.py
            -__init__.py
```

The content of my app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0')
```

And **init**.py in the name folder is:

```
from app import app
```

How would I import this app into views.py? Currently, I'm using

```
from name import app
from models import Class1
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=Class1.as_view('class1'))
```

, but then when I run the app it returns a 404 error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I did to my apps:

In `__init__.py`:

```
from .app import app

with app.app_context():
    from .folder1 import models, views  # noqa
```

In `folder1/views.py`:

```
from flask import current_app as app
# then use `app` as usual
from .models import Class1
app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=Class1.as_view('class1'))
```

The "`app_context()`" injects the current `app` object into the `current_app` proxy. Read [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/) to understand the mechanism.

Also [it is recommended](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-328) to explicitly use relative imports (with the extra dots "`.`").