# Flask-ImportError: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycode'

Tags: python, flask

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/rohit/flask/src/tests/conftest.py'.
conftest.py:6: in <module>
    from mycode import create_app
E   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mycode'
```

when running pytest form the src folder above mycode folder, it gives ModuleNotFoundError

The directory structure is as follow

```
├── mycode
│   ├── auth
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── db_insert.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   ├── auth.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── db.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   ├── db_insert.cpython-37.pyc
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── schema.sql
│   └── templates
│       ├── auth
│       │   ├── login.html
│       │   └── register.html
│       └── base.html
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py
    ├── data.sql
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── conftest.cpython-37-pytest-5.4.1.pyc
    └── test_factory.py
```

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `__init__.py` file needs to go in the folder named `mycode`. If the  above is already true then try the following.

Rename `__init__.py` to `mycode.py`

You can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44532790/6505847) for more solutions that may solve your problem.